# Calculating waterfall chart components

Tags: math

I’m trying to create a waterfall chart, but having trouble working out how to calculate the contributions from the components that gets you from budget to actual...

For example – I have a "budget" list of groceries, with a price and a quantity, and then I’ll have an "actual" grocery list with the final price and quantity… which looks like the below

**Budget**

| Item | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 2.1 | 5 |
| Oranges | 3.4 | 7 |
| Bananas | 5.1 | 10 |
| Mangos | 15.3 | 3 |
| Grapes | 3.8 | 20 |
| **Total** | **4.6** | **45** |

**Actual**

| Item | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 2.5 | 9 |
| Oranges | 3.7 | 6 |
| Bananas | 4.3 | 11 |
| Mangos | 13.3 | 4 |
| Grapes | 9.5 | 22 |
| **Total** | **6.8** | **52** |

So if the waterfall were to begin at the weighted average of $4.6 per grocery item, how do I calculate each grocery item's contribution to get to the actual weighted contribution to $6.8 per item? Is there a nice simple calculation to work this out, ensuring that it factors in changes to each item's price as well as changes in quantity...

hoping to achieve something like this waterfall:

[image: waterfall]

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate a weighted average?

Comment: @Beta no, I'm asking how to calculate contribution to the final weighted average outcome... the weighted averages are the start and end points... I just want to know how to work out how much the apples contributed to the weighted average change... and is it positive or negative ?

Answer (score 1):

Notations:

- `i` : item's number (in the example: 1 for Apples, ..., 5 for Grapes)
- `n` : number if items (in the example: 5)
- `Pb[i]` : budget price of the i-th item
- `Qb[i]` : budget quantity of the i-th item
- `Qb = Qb[1] + ... + Qb[n]` : sum of budget quantities (in the example: 45)
- `Pb = (Pb[1] * Qb[1] + ... + Pb[n] * Qb[n]) / Qb` : average budget price (in the example: 4.6)
- `Pa[i]` : actual price of the i-th item
- `Qa[i]` : actual quantity of the i-th item
- `Qa = Qa[1] + ... + Qa[n]` : sum of actual quantities (in the example: 52)
- `Pa = (Pa[1] * Qa[1] + ... + Pa[n] * Qa[n]) / Qa` : average actual price (in the example: 6.8)

You would like to calculate each item's contribution to the difference between the average actual price and the average budget price. This can be done by rearranging the difference:

```
Pa - Pb
  = (Pa[1] * Qa[1] + ... + Pa[n] * Qa[n]) / Qa - (Pb[1] * Qb[1] + ... + Pb[n] * Qb[n]) / Qb
  = (Pa[1] * Qa[1] / Qa - Pb[1] * Qb[1] / Qb) + ... + (Pa[n] * Qa[n] / Qa - Pb[n] * Qb[n] / Qb)
```

That is, the contribution of the i-ts item is `Pa[i] * Qa[i] / Qa - Pb[i] * Qb[i] / Qb`. For your example, the numbers are the following:

```
          Contribution
Apples     0.2
Oranges   -0.1
Bananas   -0.2
Mangos     0.0
Grapes     2.3
```

The sum of these contributions is 2.2, which equals to the difference between the average actual price (6.8) and the average budget price (4.6), as expected.

Comment: thanks very much for that ! let me test that with a bigger sample and I'll confirm.